# OpenMP race conditions with conditional statement

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, openmp, race-condition, reduction

I'm trying to parallelize a piece of code, I've solved the problem of dispatching in parallel the insertions in a map with a reduction. But the program gives me a memory error I think related to the conditional check on the map size. There is a conceptual error or is it possible to synchronize also that part?

```
if (PERF_ROWS == MAX_ROWS)
{
    int array_dist[PERF_ROWS];

    #pragma omp declare reduction (merge : std::multimap<float, int> : omp_out.insert(omp_in.begin(),omp_in.end()))

    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) reduction(merge: ranking_map) private(array_dist)
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_COLUMNS; i++)
    {
        if (i % PERF_CLMN == 1) continue;

        for (int j = 0; j < PERF_ROWS; j++)
        {
            array_dist[j] = abs(input[j] - input_matrix[j][i]);
        }

        float av = mean(PERF_ROWS, array_dist);

        float score = score_func(av);

        //cout<<score<<" "<<av<<endl;

        //#pragma omp critical(rank_func)
        //rank_function(score, i);

        multimap<float,int>::iterator it = ranking_map.begin();

        if (ranking_map.size() < NUM_RES)
        {
            ranking_map.insert({score, i});
        }

        else if (score > it -> first)
        {
            ranking_map.erase(it);
            ranking_map.insert({score, i});
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried the code with OpenMP disabled or by using a single thread?

Comment: Yes and it works, the problem is that enabling openmp the performance degradate. I solved the problem of the parallel dispatching of the insertion in the map with the reduction, but I don't know what to do to parallelize the conditional part, avoiding to make it critical and bottlenecking the code.

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing what you exactly want to achieve. However, operations on `ranking_map` are safe, since each thread uses a private copy. Did you adapt variables like `NUM_RES` etc. accordingly to execute with more than one thread? How is `NUM_RES` initialized for example?

Comment: NUM_RES is a global int variable, also ranking_map is global and it must be shared between the threads...I think that the problem is there, because the check on the size is made on a global map variable. My objective is to avoid to do this part pragma critical. But i don't know if it is feasible.

Comment: I think, you misunderstand the concept of `reduction`. The loop is divided into multiple parts, each one processed by a single thread. Each thread gets a copy of `ranking_map` and can independently `insert` and `erase` elements. At the end of the loop, all copies are merged together resulting in the global `ranking_map`.

Comment: OK, i know that, in fact i think that the problem is in if (ranking_map.size() < NUM_RES) because the check is made concurrently and gives me error. I know that insertions and erasing are parallelized by the reduction.

Comment: No there is nothing parallelized on `ranking_map`. You may get an error if you try to erase an empty iterator, which is the case if the `else` branch is execute before the `if` branch. But that has nothing to do with OpenMP. I can even not reproduce the issue. Show your complete code and I will give a complete answer.

Comment: Ok my problem is that I want not only to insert values in a global map (this part can be made with a reduction), but I want also to optimize that process and maintain only a fixed size map, instead of ordering thousand of values. So this is why I've made a check on the size and an erase.

Comment: there is a difference between map<float,int>::iterator and multimap<float, int>::iterator......
for such cases use auto

i think this should fix your problem, but i am not sure, cause i didn't tested it

Comment: Ok i've fixed it, thank you for the advice, but the problem is still unresolved...I want to make that part not critical but in parallel

Comment: the memory exception remains?

Comment: yes, i've setted the iterator on auto but the error remains

Comment: well, i am also not sure whether there is an given order for omp, if the private can be stated after the reduction, i never tested this out, also you should make sure that your arrays are big enough
and please note, that every thread get's something like a provate copy from ranking_map, so it might not work to reduce the size of your container this way

Answer (score 0):

Well, define your own combiner.
Make a function called insertwhatever and write something like this:

```
    void insertwhatever(std::multimap<float, int>& a, std::multimap<float, int>&b)
     {
     for(auto iterb : b)
     {
      if(a.size() < NUM_RES)
      {
       a.insert(iterb);
      }
      else if(....)
      {
      (dont know what you want to do here)
      }
     }
    }
```

Then change the reduction in

```
#pragma omp declare reduction (merge : std::multimap<float, int> : insertwhatever(omp_out,omp_in))
```

I am not perfectly sure but i think this should work. Still i don't really understand what exeactly you are trying to do.

Comment: OK I want to do exactly this, to make parallel this piece. Instead of only insert values in map, I want to maintain a fixed size of the map avoiding to maintain ordered a lot of values. this is why the else if...

Comment: But I want to insert only two values, score and I, the map is global